# How to select random element using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I use ng-repeat below  :

```
<div ng-repeat="quote in quotes">
        {{quote.value}}
</div>
```

to iterate over a quotes variable :

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope){
    $scope.quotes = [
        {
            value: "q1"
        },
        {
            value: "q2"
        },

    ];
});
```

I would like to select just one random element from this quotes variable instead of iterating over the entire array. Is there a directive in angualrjs I can use to achieve this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this: "[Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array) to get a random value.

```
$scope.randomQuote = $scope.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.quotes.length)];
```

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this without any of directives if they're not found:
The following method randomize an int within a range

```
getRandomIndex = function(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

So in our case: min should be zero and max should be the length of the array - 1

### Here is an example how to use it

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope){
$scope.getRandomIndex = function(length){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
}
    $scope.quotes = [
        {
            value: "q1"
        },
        {
            value: "q2"
        },

    ];
});

<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <div ng-repeat="q in quotes">
        <p> {{quotes[getRandomIndex(quotes.length)].value}} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```